# How do I add a path that has a colon in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile that was included in the nRF52 sdk for one of the Bluetooth examples.
I want to make a copy of the file and move it, hence I need to update some parameters.

The part of the makefile I changed looks as such

```
SDK_ROOT := C:/Nordic_SDKS/nRF5SDK1702d674dde
```

It previously was the relative path using ../../../

When I run make I get the following output

```
make: *** No rule to make target `C\:/Nordic_SDKS/nRF5SDK1702d674dde/modules/nrfx/mdk/gcc_startup_nrf52.S', needed by `_build/nrf52832_xxaa/gcc_startup_nrf52.S.o'.  Stop.
```

My Knowledge of Makefiles is very limited, but I presume the inserted "\" after the C directory is the reason the recipe is failing, since without that backslash that file exists.

Is there a way to stop this from happening, or am I wrong with what the problem is?

Comment: make tells you that to build `_build/nrf52832_xxaa/gcc_startup_nrf52.S.o` it needs `C\:/Nordic_SDKS/nRF5SDK1702d674dde/modules/nrfx/mdk/gcc_startup_nrf52.S` which it did not find and does not know how to build. So, the first question to answer is: do you have a `C\:/Nordic_SDKS/nRF5SDK1702d674dde/modules/nrfx/mdk/gcc_startup_nrf52.S` file? If not, did you tell make how to create it (in your Makefile)?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

Escaping in Windows/Batch File can be done with a carrot like C^:/Nordic instead of \ but I don't think it's your issue.

Change

```
SDK_ROOT := C:/Nordic_SDKS/nRF5SDK1702d674dde
```

to

```
SDK_ROOT := C:\Nordic_SDKS\nRF5SDK1702d674dde
```

Then of course verify the path/name combo truly exist with copy and paste to look for typos.  In a command prompt

```
dir C:\Nordic_SDKS\nRF5SDK1702d674dde\modules\nrfx\mdk\gcc_startup_nrf52.S
```